# How to upload files to DigitalOcean spaces using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, digital-ocean

I need code to upload files to digitalocean spaces using codeigniter.

And get the file path.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried anything? i guess they have properly written docs to achieve this. did you get an error trying out their apis

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: I could not understand their docs. They have not given any sample code.

Comment: take a look at this: https://github.com/SociallyDev/Spaces-API . this might make things easier for you

Answer (score -1):

take a look at this: https://github.com/SociallyDev/Spaces-API . this might make things easier for you

After you initialise, you can easily upload any file like this:

```
$space->UploadFile($path_to_file, "public");
```

`$space` is the instance of `SpacesConnect`

Rest is on its git page

Comment: I think there's no reference that he's using this library to upload the files.

Comment: @marcogmonteiro why downvote? I know there's no reference that he's using this library  it's a suggestion that he could use this library

Comment: and you did suggest it, in the comments. No need to do it a second time.